# How to get data from JSON object? Choice from date variable to chart

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON object with 3 variable: DateTime, entry_id, field1.

```
{"created_at":"2018-11-14T18:38:13Z","entry_id":157,"field1":"294"}
```

I want to have 2 listbox with DataTime value. First listbox is 'date from' and second 'date to'. When the user selects the values ​​from two lists, variables field1 will show up in the graph.

I want to get data from json and set this to chart, but i want to choose date from list box

I know how to set one value from json to chart, but how i can do a choice date from, to?

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient()){
        string rawJson = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/618749/feeds.json?results=");

        RootObject dataColletion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawJson);

        Console.WriteLine(dataColletion.feeds.Count);

        AllData = dataColletion.feeds;
    }

    private static List<Feed> allDane;

    public static List<Feed> AllData
    {
        get{ return allDane; }

        set{ allDane = value; }
    }

    public static List<Feed> GetDane()
    {
        return AllData;
    }
```

Comment: from json which date will be `date from` and `date to`?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer, but I don't think it has anything do to with JSON

Comment: I want to get data from json and set this to chart, but i want to choose date from list box